# Selective string reduction

Tags: php, regex, string, str-replace

I would like to know how to strip all non-alphanumeric characters from a string except for underscores and dashes in PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^\w-]/', '', $str);
```

The first argument to `preg_replace` is a regular expression.  This one contains:

- `/` - starting delimiter -- start the regex
- `[` - start character class -- define characters that can be matched
- `^` - negative -- make the character class match only characters that don't match the selection that follows
- `\w` - word character -- so don't match word characters. These are `A-Za-z0-9` and `_` (underscore)
- `-` - hyphen -- don't match hypens either
- `]` - close the character class
- `/` - ending delimiter -- close the regex

Note that this only matches hyphens (i.e. -).  It does not match genuine dash characters (– or —).

Comment: Unfortunately this leaves in currency... and other various word-like characters...

Comment: @SkippyChalmers Um, really? Like which? `\w` is `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: uh oh. You're right about what it should be. I'm sensing being incorrect. However rubular and my other regex editor is matching '£'. Could be a bug! Either way...

Comment: @Skippy So why does `preg_match('/\w/', '£')` return `0` in PHP then?

Comment: Yeah, rubular is broken. Ruby (as it's PCRE) also defines `\w` like `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: Hands down, you're on the money. I respectfully retract. Will leave these comments up for others to learn from. Will also fire something over to rubular. +1

Comment: This depends on the current `locale`. PCRE can match all sorts of other characters with `\w` if it isn't set to `C`/`en`. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php for the by-text on `\w`

Answer (score 7):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) with `/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]/` as the pattern and `''` as the replacement.

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]/', '', $string);
```

**EDIT**

As skippy said, you can use the `i` modifier for case insensitivity:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-]/i', '', $string);
```

Comment: (+1) Nitpick: You don't technically need the backslash as long as the hyphen is the last character in the square brackets. :)

Comment: I like this :) you could use the case insensitive modifier and I admire your discipline in escaping the dash ;) I'm too lazy to do that when it doesn't need doing. +1

Comment: @SkippyChalmers Thanks! Forgot about the modifier :p

Answer (score 1):

Accepts a-z, A-Z, 0-9, '-', '_' and spaces:

```
$str = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\s_-]+/i", '', $tr);
```

No spaces:

```
$str = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_-]+/i", '', $tr);
```